Could I translate any meaning of "abandon" as "утратить"?
I have looked the word up in several key English dictionaries, and it seems that all the translations effectively regard утратить as an equivalent of the English word "abandon".
Is this right?

Утратить is not "to abandon"; it is "to forfeit". "Abandon" is покинуть/оставить. A man can "abandon" his family (оставить семью). This is not the same as "forfeit".
I checked Google, and forgive the newsworthy example, but Украина неизбежно утратит значительную часть своих территорий is on Google. That country will inevitably forfeit a considerable part of its territories (or "its territory", which may make more sense in idiomatic English).

"To abandon all hope" could be translated as "утратить последнюю надежду", among other possibilities. More common would be "потерять последнюю надежду".

I think correct translation will be "оставить последнюю надежду". In contrast to "to loose all hope" which will translate to "утратить/потерять последнюю надежду".

I see no difference in meaning between "lose hope" and "abandon hope", and because the original question was whether there is a context when this translation would fit, I think this example is suitable. "Оставить надежду" is an equally good translation but does not change the meaning.

The difference between "отавить" and "потерять" is that former is intentional and lat

Not in this context. How can you intentionally abandon hope unless you lost it? Makes no sense. But my wife is a philosopher and she says, like you, that there is difference and one can intentionally abandon hope that is not yet lost. :-) So let it be so.
